# Where can I find the source code for Memgraph Lab?

Tags: memgraphdb

I've found Memgraph repository at https://github.com/memgraph/memgraph but I don't see the Memgraph Lab code in it. Where can I find it?

I've tried to use GitHub search to locate the code but I couldn't find it.

Comment: It just isn't my day today. I should come back latter when stress level goes down :)

Comment: Just get a latte and relax :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't find it since it isn't open sourced. You can download Memgrpah Lab or use it as part of Docker Platform.

There is one component of Memgraph Lab that is opened sourced - Orb. Orb is a graph visualization library that is used within Memgraph Lab and you can see the code at https://github.com/memgraph/orb.